# Animated Short About a Hand in a Flower Pot

Tags: story-identification, animation

I saw this between 2000 and 2005, guessing it's 5 to 10 minutes long. Think it looked like a drawing on a chalkboard; with a dark background and colored lines, it was 2D animation.

It depicts someone leaving a flower pot in a green house, we are shown it has a little blue hand growing in it, the hand develops and realizes there's a pink female hand in a flower pot inside a greenhouse across a valley. Through their gestures we understand they realize about each other and wanna be together but they are stuck in their pots. The male hand grows, it becomes burly, then it's a whole strong arm that barely fits in the pot. The hand tears itself from the planter and emerges as a blue male figure, its counterpart does the same and it's now a pink female figure, they break the glass of their greenhouses, run down the hills and meet in the middle of the valley, the couple embraces and fuses into a tree, the tree grows and grows, then we see little blossoms on its branches; they flower into little colored hands.

I made [an animatic](https://gemoo.com/tools/upload-video/share/590501488328929280?codeId=PYx8dYzlaLZn4&card=590501484549861376) approximating what I remember, needless to say the music is not the original.

I saw this in a channel called Locomotion in the early 2000's, most likely in a block that they had, called *Locotomia*, in which they showed experimental/international animation. The channel ceased to exist in 2005, I know it operated in Latin America, Portugal, Spain and Florida, they had HQs in Buenos Aires, Miami and Toronto. I myself watched it in Argentina

[image]

Comment: Very nice animatic!

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F.  Where was at that you saw this?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks. I saw this in a channel called Locomotion in the early 2000's, most likely in a block that they had, called Locotomia, in which they showed experimental/international animation. The channel ceased to exist in 2005, I know it operated in Latin America, Portugal, Spain and Florida, they had HQs in Buenos Aires, Miami and Toronto. I myself watched it in Argentina.